# How to vertically center text in a line?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have some lines of the text, and those lines contains words with different sizes of fonts. I want to align them vertically to the center of a line instead of bottom. I'm using Microsoft Word 2003. I include an image to show what I mean:

[image: The problem]

Answer (score 4):

If all the larger text in your document will be the same font size, and all the smaller text will be the same, select one bit of smaller text, and then, in the **Font** dialog box, on the **Advanced** tab, select **Raised** in the **Position** field, and then set the **By** value to a value that puts the text at the height that you want. Then create a character style for the smaller text. If the correctly styled smaller text is selected when you create the new style, the new style will have the properties of that text by default. (Instead of creating a new style, you could repurpose one of Word's existing styles, updating it to match the style of the smaller text). Then apply the style to all relevant text.

Alternatively, depending on the characteristics of the specific font that you're using, and the specific sizes that you're using, just styling the smaller text as a superscript by clicking the **Superscript** button might get you vertical centered text, or at least close enough to look convincing.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

1. Create a table consisting of two cells.
2. Write the large text in one cell and the small text in another
3. Open the properties of each cell and set the vertical alignment to middle.
4. Select the whole table and hide its borders.

Although I know all these are possible, I can't give you a screenshot showing how to do them because I don't have access to this 14-years-old product.

Comment: Thank you. I know this way, it requires creating a new cell for each change of the font size.